# Django's AttributeError for PointField()

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I have a problem with my Django database. When I enter: `python manage.py makemigrations`. I got this exception: `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'PointField'`. Here is my very simple code that cause the issue:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

# Create your models here.
class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,editable=False)
    location = models.PointField()  # The culprit
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Thank you in advance.

It supposed to make changes to my PostgreSQL database. Well the database hasn't been made yet, I already initialize it with SQLite **WITHOUT THE CODE ABOVE. IT WAS INITIALIZED BEFORE THERE IS ANYTHING IN THE MODELS FILES**, trying to switch to PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, I need to import `from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField` and change the field to `location = PointField()`

Now it worked fine after installing GDAL, OSGeo4W, and PostGIS, then changing the database engine in the settings file to `'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',`

Comment: Now I just have to get GDAL library to work on Windows, that will be fun.

Answer (score 0):

It is what error says. Even you pointed out. `django.db.models` does not have anything named `PointField`. So check this link from django docs and Select proper field type for your data.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/

best of luck

Comment: I see, it seems that I need GIS, I'll look into it, and maybe I could answer the question further.